# Magento form validation doesn't work as user type in

Tags: magento2, customer-account, forms, validation, form-validation

I have added `form validation` for the customer address form.
but the issue is, validation works when I click submit button, it should work as user types in(key-up).

> city text box

```
<input type="text" name="city" value="" title="City" class="input-text required-entry mage-error" id="city" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-alphanum-with-spaces':true}" sr-only="INPUT" for="INPUT" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="city-error">
```

> postcode text box

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" value="" title="Zip/Postal Code" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international required-entry mage-error" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-alphanum-with-spaces':true}" sr-only="INPUT" for="INPUT" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="zip-error">
```

script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#form-validate": {
        "addressValidation": {}
    },
    "#country": {
        "regionUpdater": {
            "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
            "regionListId": "#region_id",
            "regionInputId": "#region",
            "postcodeId": "#zip",
            "form": "#form-validate",
            "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getRegionJson() ?>,
            "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getRegionId() ?>",
            "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
        }
    }
}
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: please refer this link maybe helpful for you  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224243/magento-2-how-to-validate-customer-registration-form-on-keyup-event